# Vuejs not updating list but updating obect

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I am learning `Vuejs` and I am stuck. Why can I see the messages get added to the object (in Chrome Vue debugger) yet it is not added to the div that contains the list?

My Vue Component:

```
<template>
    <div id="round-status-message" class="round-status-message">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" v-for="sysmessage in sysmessages" v-html="sysmessage.message"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['sysmessages'],

        methods: {
            scrollToTop () {
                this.$el.scrollTop = 0
            }
        }

    };
</script>
```

My Vue instance:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    Vue.component('chat-system', require('../components/chat-system.vue'));

    var chatSystem = new Vue({
        el: '#system-chat',

        data: function () {
            return {
                sysmessages: []
            };
        },

        created() {
            this.fetchMessages();

            Echo.private(sys_channel)
                .listen('SystemMessageSent', (e) => {

                    this.sysmessages.unshift({
                        sysmessage: e.message.message,
                    });

                    this.processMessage(e);

                });

        },

        methods: {
            fetchMessages() {
                axios.get(sys_get_route)
                .then(response => {
                    this.sysmessages = response.data;
                });
            },

            processMessage(message) {

                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    this.$refs.sysmessages.scrollToTop();
                });

                // updateGame();

            }
        }
    });

});
```

My template call in HTML:

```
<div id="system-chat">
    <chat-system ref="sysmessages" v-on:systemmessagesent="processMessage" :sysmessages="sysmessages" :player="{{ Auth::user() }}"></chat-system>
</div>
```

There are no compile or run time errors and I can see records added to the `props` in the vue chrome tool. I can also see empty HTML elements added to the div.

What have I missed?

UPDATE: My record structures:

`response.data` is an array of objects, each like this:

```
{"data":[
     {"id":100,
      "progress_id":5,
      "message":"start message",
      "action":"welcome"
     },
     {"id"....
```

`e.message.message` contains the text message entry, so just a string.

I am trying to access the `message` variable in each object during the `fetchMessages` method.

Comment: Hi @Bert, your suggestion fixed my problem but it broke the `fetchMessages `piece now.

Comment: How did it break it? Ideally, what is the structure of `response.data` and `e.message`.

Comment: Hi @Bert I added the records

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're adding objects with `sysmessage` as the property.

```
this.sysmessages.unshift({
  sysmessage: e.message.message,
});
```

But you are trying to view

```
v-for="sysmessage in sysmessages" v-html="sysmessage.message"
```

Based on your update, the code should be:

```
this.sysmessages.unshift({
  message: e.message.message,
});
```

And you can leave the template as

```
v-html="sysmessage.message"
```